# C# lambda expression Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new in C# and I don't understand how to specify args in lambda expressions. I have following code:

```
Dictionary<string,string> MyDictionary = some key + some value;

var myReultList= MyDictionary.Select(MyMethod).ToList();
var myReult= await Task.WhenAll(myReultList);

private async Task<string> MyMethod(string arg1, string arg2){
    //do some async work and return value
}
```

how to specify dictionary key as `arg1` and dictionary value as `arg2` ?

in this code I get error at 2nd row:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method `Enumerable.Select<TSource,
>   TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)` cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Comment: `MyDictionary.Select(kvp => return MyMethod(kvp.Key,kvp.Value).ToList()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elements of a `Dictionary<string, string>` are `KeyValuePair<string, string>` so you need to change the parameter type of `MyMethod` to match:

```
private async Task<string> MyMethod(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair) 
{
        string arg1 = pair.Key;
        string arg2 = pair.Value;
        ...
}
```

alternatively you could unpack the values in a lambda:

```
var myResultList = MyDictionary.Select(kvp => MyMethod(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToList();
```